# $A, B$ are symmetric and $A^{3}$ is similar to $B^{3}$ only if $A$ is similar to $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Claim.**
Let $A,B$ be symmetric matrices; let $A^{3}$ be similar to $B^{3}$; then $A$ is similar to $B$.

If $A,B$ are symmetric, then there are some invertible $Q_{1},Q_{2}$ and some diagonal $D_{1},D_{2}$ such that
$A = Q_{1}^{-1}D_{1}Q_{1}$ and $B= Q_{2}^{-1}D_{2}Q_{2}$, implying that
$A^{3} = Q_{1}^{-1}D_{1}^{3}Q_{1}$ and $B^{3} = Q_{2}^{-1}D_{2}^{3}Q_{2}$; if $A^{3}$ is similar to $B^{3}$, then there is some invertible $Q_{3}$ such that
$$
A^{3} = Q_{1}^{-1}D_{1}^{3}Q_{1} = Q_{3}^{-1}Q_{2}^{-1}D_{2}^{3}Q_{2}Q_{3} = Q_{3}^{-1}B^{3}Q_{3}.$$

Here I am currently blinded to see how to conclude that $A$ is similar to $B$... Maybe this way does not have an exit...

Comment: Maybe it helps if you first consider diagonal matrices. Can you show that if $D_1^3$ and $D_2^3$ are similar, then $D_1$ and $D_2$ are similar?

Comment: The other way around is clear; but this direction is unclear... @DanielFischer

Comment: When are two diagonal matrices similar?

Comment: If you have got an idea and find time, please feel free to make an answer :) @DanielFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it clearer if you note that multiplication of diagonal matrices are just multiplication of the elements? That is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}d_1&0& \cdots & 0\\
                  0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
                 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                  0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n
                  \end{pmatrix}^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}d_1^3&0& \cdots & 0\\
                  0 & d_2^3 & \cdots & 0 \\
                 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                  0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n^3
                  \end{pmatrix} $$

Note that if $A=PBP^{-1}$ and $Au = \lambda u$ we have

$$PBP^{-1}u = \lambda u$$
$$BP^{-1}u = P^{-1}\lambda u = \lambda P^{-1}u$$

so if $A$ and $B$ are similar it means that they share the same eigenvalues. Also note that if $u$ and $v$ are linear independent eigenvectors to $A$ then $P^{-1}u$ and $P^{-1}v$ are also independent.

This means that for diagonal matrices to be similar their diagonal elemnts must be a permutation of the other. But if the diagonal elements cubed of $D_1$ is a permutation of those of $D_2$ the same is true for the diagonal elements themselves that is $D_1$ is similar to $D_2$.

Comment: Thank you; I did not link the problem to eigenvalues... :)